# Reference two columns in a lambda function in the aggregate method on a grouped DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

I have the following DataFrame:

|  | Paid_Taxes | Lodging | Arrival_date | Departure_Date | Institution | USER_CODE | FACILITY_ID | COD_AUTH | MANAGER_TAXID | MANAGER_SURNAME | MANAGER_NAME | Booking_Source | Nights | Booking_ID | Guest_Code | Name | Year | Month | Period | Guests |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 6.0 | My-B&B | 2023-02-03 | 2023-02-05 | U432 | U432543453543 | 23294 | 4395832fh343j | RSSMRA80P10B602Z | Rossi | Mario | Hotel.com | 2 | 8796059-(1641973827-2968541682) | 1 | Alessandra Rossi | 2023 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0.0 | My-B&B | 2023-02-03 | 2023-02-05 | U432 | U432543453543 | 23294 | 4395832fh343j | RSSMRA80P10B602Z | Rossi | Mario | Hotel.com | 2 | 9874036-(4987051672-3079823164) | 2 | Carlotta Bianchi | 2023 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 12.0 | My-B&B | 2023-03-09 | 2023-03-11 | U432 | U432543453543 | 23294 | 4395832fh343j | RSSMRA80P10B602Z | Rossi | Mario | Vacation.com | 4 | 3689027-(7098192456-5219374608) | 1 | Irina Petrova | 2023 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 18.0 | My-B&B | 2023-03-27 | 2023-03-30 | U432 | U432543453543 | 23294 | 4395832fh343j | RSSMRA80P10B602Z | Rossi | Mario | Hotel.com | 6 | 3872106-(5412683907-0931874256) | 1 | Cristina Sanchez | 2023 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 24.0 | My-B&B | 2023-03-15 | 2023-03-19 | U432 | U432543453543 | 23294 | 4395832fh343j | RSSMRA80P10B602Z | Rossi | Mario | Hotel.com | 8 | 4169508-(7284310592-0653897214) | 1 | Stefan Nikolov | 2023 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 18.0 | My-B&B | 2023-03-23 | 2023-03-26 | U432 | U432543453543 | 23294 | 4395832fh343j | RSSMRA80P10B602Z | Rossi | Mario | Hotel.com | 6 | 5403918-(6728159304-1738594286) | 1 | Mikkel Jensen | 2023 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 6 | 12.0 | My-B&B | 2023-03-31 | 2023-04-01 | U432 | U432543453543 | 23294 | 4395832fh343j | RSSMRA80P10B602Z | Rossi | Mario | Vacation.com | 2 | 8514967-(6289413057-6403891725) | 1 | Davide Moretti | 2023 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 7 | 12.0 | My-B&B | 2023-04-01 | 2023-04-02 | U432 | U432543453543 | 23294 | 4395832fh343j | RSSMRA80P10B602Z | Rossi | Mario | Hotel.com | 2 | 8209315-(0462815739-8410932576) | 1 | Davide Moretti | 2023 | 4 | 2 | 0 |

I need to aggregate this DataFrame and create some new columns. I also want to delete some columns not needed after the aggregation.

The code I use for the aggregation is:

```py
df = (
    df.groupby(
        ['Institution', 'USER_CODE', 'FACILITY_ID', 'Year', 'Period', 'Month', 'Guest_Code', 'Booking_Source'],
        as_index=False,
    )
    .agg(**column_map)
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

where **Guest_Code** identifies the type of guest, and **Period** identifies the quarter of the year.

`column_map` in the code above is define here:

```py
# columns to be deleted after the aggregation
cols_to_del = ['Booking_ID', 'Arrival_date', 'Departure_Date', 'Name', 'Guests', 'Nights']

# columns I want to keep
column_map = {col: pd.NamedAgg(column=col, aggfunc='first') for col in df.columns if col not in cols_to_del}

# The amount of taxes paid in the same month for each Guest_Code and Booking_Source
column_map['Paid_Taxes'] = pd.NamedAgg(column='Paid_Taxes', aggfunc='sum')

# the total amount of guests in the month divided by guest code and booking source
column_map['All_arrives_per_Month-GuestCode-Source'] = pd.NamedAgg(column='Guests', aggfunc='sum')

# the total amount of nights in the month divided by guest code and booking source
column_map['All_nights_per_Month-GuestCode-Source'] = pd.NamedAgg(column='Nights', aggfunc='sum')

# the total amount of guest who are exempt to pay city taxes (basically who is guest_code=2)
column_map['All_tax-exempt_per_Month-Source'] = pd.NamedAgg(
    column='Guests',
    aggfunc=lambda x: x['Guests'].sum()
    if x[x['Guest_Code'] == 2].shape[0] > 1
    else x['Guests'].to_frame()
    if x[x['Guest_Code'] == 2].shape[0] == 1
    else pd.DataFrame([0], columns=['Guests']),
)
```

Everything works fine except the last row:

```py
column_map['All_tax-exempt_per_Month-Source'] = pd.NamedAgg(
    column='Guests',
    aggfunc=lambda x: x['Guests'].sum()
    if x[x['Guest_Code'] == 2].shape[0] > 1
    else x['Guests'].to_frame()
    if x[x['Guest_Code'] == 2].shape[0] == 1
    else pd.DataFrame([0], columns=['Guests'])
)
```

I understand that it fails because `x` is a *Series* representing `df['Guests']`, so `x['Guest_Code']` in the lambda function cannot be called. If I was able to define multiple columns in the NamedAgg class, that would have been great. Unfortunately that is not possible at the moment *(even if I am not the only one asking for this feature)*, but I really cannot see another way to obtain a column that is the sum of the number of exempt guests if there are more than one row with `Guest_Code=2` in the considered group, or it is the number of guests if in the group there is just one row, or eventually 0 if the group doesn't have any row with `Guest_Code=2`.

Here is code to create the DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Paid_Taxes': [6.0, 0.0, 12.0, 18.0, 24.0, 18.0, 12.0, 12.0],
        'Lodging': ['My-B&B', 'My-B&B', 'My-B&B', 'My-B&B', 'My-B&B', 'My-B&B', 'My-B&B', 'My-B&B'],
        'Arrival_date': ['2023-02-03', '2023-02-03', '2023-03-09', '2023-03-27', '2023-03-15', '2023-03-23', '2023-03-31', '2023-04-01'],
        'Departure_Date': ['2023-02-05', '2023-02-05', '2023-03-11', '2023-03-30', '2023-03-19', '2023-03-26', '2023-04-01', '2023-04-02'],
        'Institution': ['U432', 'U432', 'U432', 'U432', 'U432', 'U432', 'U432', 'U432'],
        'USER_CODE': ['U432543453543', 'U432543453543', 'U432543453543', 'U432543453543', 'U432543453543', 'U432543453543', 'U432543453543', 'U432543453543'],
        'FACILITY_ID': [23294, 23294, 23294, 23294, 23294, 23294, 23294, 23294],
        'COD_AUTH': ['4395832fh343j', '4395832fh343j', '4395832fh343j', '4395832fh343j', '4395832fh343j', '4395832fh343j', '4395832fh343j', '4395832fh343j'],
        'MANAGER_TAXID': ['RSSMRA80P10B602Z', 'RSSMRA80P10B602Z', 'RSSMRA80P10B602Z', 'RSSMRA80P10B602Z', 'RSSMRA80P10B602Z', 'RSSMRA80P10B602Z', 'RSSMRA80P10B602Z', 'RSSMRA80P10B602Z'],
        'MANAGER_SURNAME': ['Rossi', 'Rossi', 'Rossi', 'Rossi', 'Rossi', 'Rossi', 'Rossi', 'Rossi'],
        'MANAGER_NAME': ['Mario', 'Mario', 'Mario', 'Mario', 'Mario', 'Mario', 'Mario', 'Mario'],
        'Booking_Source': ['Hotel.com', 'Hotel.com', 'Vacation.com', 'Hotel.com', 'Hotel.com', 'Hotel.com', 'Vacation.com', 'Hotel.com'],
        'Nights': [2, 2, 4, 6, 8, 6, 2, 2],
        'Booking_ID': ['8796059-(1641973827-2968541682)', '9874036-(4987051672-3079823164)', '3689027-(7098192456-5219374608)', '3872106-(5412683907-0931874256)', '4169508-(7284310592-0653897214)', '5403918-(6728159304-1738594286)', '8514967(6289413057-6403891725)', '8209315-(0462815739-8410932576)'],
        'Guest_Code': [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        'Name': ['Alessandra Rossi', 'Carlotta Bianchi', 'Irina Petrova', 'Cristina Sanchez', 'Stefan Nikolov', 'Mikkel Jensen', 'Davide Moretti', 'Davide Moretti'],
        'Year': [2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023],
        'Month': [2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4],
        'Period': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
        'Guests': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
    }
)
```

Comment: The table given in the example seems incorrect. Please check and correct it.

Comment: It looks like `Guest_Code` was split in half with a tab? And something else happened causing the values to the right of `Guest_Code` to be shifted over a couple columns.

Comment: You could create a new column before the groupby e.g. `df.assign(Guests_Exempt = ...).groupby` leaving you a single column you can sum inside the aggregation.

Comment: @IanThompson, you are right: in the original table definition, some complex values had a pipe to divide each component, and that was misunderstood by the interpreter. I changed the pipe with a dash to avoid the problem. I also modified the definition of the DataFrame so that it corresponds to the data in the table.

Comment: @jqurious, can you please explain better?

Comment: Create a `Guests_Exempt` column before the groupby that contains the `Guests` value or `0` depending on the `Guest_Code` criteria.